# リストで抽出したデータをsqlite3(データベース)に格納したい

Tags: python, database, sqlite

■抽出後データ：変数名：name
['nameA', 'nameB', 'nameC', 'nameD']

■sqlite3：テーブル名：user
header:name

■sqlite3格納後
name
nameA
nameB
nameC
nameD

上記のように格納したい。
下記のようにやってみたが、変数nameがそのまま１行に入ってしまう。
リストに入っているnameA〜Dを１行ずつデータベースに格納したい。

```
# 変数
name = '\n'.join(name)

# DB処理

dbpath = "user.db"
con = sqlite3.connect(dbpath)
cursor = con.cursor()

sql = 'INSERT INTO user(name)VALUES(?)'
cursor.execute(sql, (name,))
con.commit()
con.close
```

Answer (score 1):

上記のうち、`name = '\n'.join(name)` の処理は行わないで、`cursor.execute(sql, (name,))` の部分を以下のようにしてみてください。

```
for entry in name:
    cursor.execute(sql, (entry,))
```

Comment: できました。一つずつ取り出して格納するということですね。ありがとうございます。